# Android Studio: how to figure out which property defines element color

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Is there any way to figure out which property defines element color using Flutter Inspector etc?

For example I have an App Bar with some text in it. Is it it possible to find whereis it set to the current color?

In this case I was searching top to bottom: in ThemeData smth about App Bar, in AppBarTheme smth about Text Style or Color. But I think that it could be done faster form the other side.
[image]
Android Studio Arctix Fox 2020.3.1.